# SQL query displaying one column and multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have a couple of tables...one contains sites and another contains some users. There is a link binding specific users to specific sites. When I run my query:

```
select sites.site, users.fullname
from sites
inner join users
on sites.nameid = users.id;
```

I get the following output:

```
 SITE  | FULLNAME

site A | John Doe
site B | John Doe
site C | John Doe
site D | Roger Rabbit
site E | Roger Rabbit
site F | Batman
```

What I'm looking for is one FULLNAME with the list of sites below:

```
  SITE | FULLNAME

site A | John Doe
site B
site C
site D | Roger Rabbit
site E
site F | Batman
```

I don't know if this is even possible or if I have to use something else to get the format I'm looking for.

I'm going to add some more details here that I should have included....first off...my query has changed to this:

```
    SELECT completed.date, users.username, iata.code, tasks.task 
FROM completed     
JOIN users         
ON users.id = completed.name     
JOIN iata         
ON iata.id = completed.code     
JOIN tasks         
ON tasks.id = completed.task
WHERE MONTH(completed.date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(completed.date) = YEAR(NOW());
```

That gives me everything I want...my php /html that I'm using to display looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>SPOC Report</title>
      <meta charset=utf-8>
   </head>

   <body>
        <?php 
        require 'db/spoc_config.php';
        ?>

        <?php

        $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql_count = "
SELECT completed.date, users.username, iata.code, tasks.task 
FROM completed     
JOIN users         
ON users.id = completed.name     
JOIN iata         
ON iata.id = completed.code     
JOIN tasks         
ON tasks.id = completed.task
WHERE MONTH(completed.date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(completed.date) = YEAR(NOW());
";  

        $result_count = $conn->query($sql_count);

        $count = mysqli_fetch_row($result_count);
        $str_count = implode($count);

         date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
         $today = date('l, jS F Y');
         $week = date('W');
         $to = "johndoe@me.com";
         $subject = "SPOC: Monthly Report " . $today;        
         $heading = "<b>SPOC Report: </b>";

         $message = "<h2>" . $heading . " " . $today . "</h2>"; 
         $message .= '<table style="font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#333333;border-width: 1px;border-color: #666666;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 2px;">';
         $message .= '
         <th style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #dedede;">Spoc</th> 
         <th style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #dedede;">Site</th>
         <th style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #dedede;">Task</th>';

         if ($result_count->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result_count->fetch_assoc()) {
         $message .= '<tr style="white-space: normal;line-height: normal;font-weight: normal;font-variant: normal;font-style: normal;text-align: start;">
          <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["username"].'</td>
          <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["code"].'</br></td>
          <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["task"].'</br></td>
          </tr>';
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
         $message .= '</table>';


         $header = "From:johndoe@me.com \r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header,'-fjohndoe@me.com');


         $conn->close();
        ?>     
   </body>
</html>
```

The output however looks like this:

```
SPOC        | SITE   | TASK

JohnDoe     | SITE A | TASK1
JohnDoe     | SITE A | TASK2
JohnDoe     | SITE B | TASK1
JohnDoe     | SITE C | TASK1
ROGERRABBIT | SITE A | TASK1
ROGERRABBIT | SITE A | TASK2
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
JohnDoe     | Site A | TASK1, TASK2, TASK3
JohnDoe     | Site B | Task1, Task2
RogerRabbit | Site A | tASk1, Task2
```

Hope this clear it up a bit. Sorry folks for the confusion.

Comment: I am thinking you might try querying the user and then list the sites for that user instead of querying the sites and listing each site along with each entry to that site. I'm sorry I can't elaborate, I'm leaving the house right now.

Comment: Where is your current php code that creates your current layout? A simple step would be to use a variable to hold the current `FULLNAME`, i.e. `$currentFULLNAME`. If the value row matches the `$currentFULLNAME` value you don't echo out the row `FULLNAME`. If the row value doesn't match, you set `$currentFULLNAME` to the new name and echo out the row value

Comment: I would not try and get that result in SQL, that's gonna be rather tedious to accomplish. Simply do it while outputting those records via the PHP script - all you have to implement is just a basic one-level _group break_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but it might help:

```
SELECT users.fullname, GROUP_CONCAT(sites.site ORDER BY sites.site SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM sites 
LEFT JOIN users ON sites.nameid = users.id
GROUP BY users.id;
```

This outputs:

```
John Doe     | site A, site B, site C
Roger Rabbit | site D, site E
Batman       | site F
```

To get exactly the result you want, I would do this in my PHP script.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the php above...sorry about that, should have done it in the first place.

Comment: You should be able to get what you want with the `GROUP_CONCAT` function applied on task (with ', ' as separator), and GROUP BY applied on users and sites. Just give it a try using my previous answer and let us know if you run into big troubles. ^^

Answer (score 0):

There must be a primary key column such as USER ID from both two tables so as to execute the following Query

```
select a.site,b.fullname from site a, users b where a.id = b.id
```